# Button of UserControl vanishes when program is debugged

Tags: vb.net

My UserControl button disappears when I debug my program. I have checked the code including the designer.vb code countless times there's nothing that makes the button `.enabled = false` or `.visible = false`. Any ideas why this is happening?

On my UserControl:

```
 Private Sub btn_Begin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Begin.Click
    Start_Race()
End Sub

Public Sub Start_Race()
    TimeNow(Past_Time)
    TimeNow(Start_Time)
    lbl_Start_Time_Driver.Text = Past_Time
    btn_Begin.BackColor = Color.Green
    btn_Begin.Text = "Started!"
End Sub

Public Property Active_bool As Boolean
    Get
        Return btn_Begin.Visible
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        btn_Begin.Visible = value
    End Set
End Property
```

On Form1:

```
Private Sub btn_Start_All_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Start_All.Click
    Dim allActiveUserControls = From uc_Index In Controls.OfType(Of LapTimerGUI)()
    Where uc_Index.Active_bool
    For Each User_Control In allActiveUserControls
        User_Control.Start_Race()
    Next
End Sub
```

*I do Google my head off before I post my ridiculous questions here btw :)*

Comment: Nobody can answer this without seeing the code.

Comment: I added all the code envolving said button, please help me D: I'm loosing my hair @LarsTech

Comment: I might "simply" the case, that because you are debugging, the UI-Thread can't redraw the control. This is normal and AFAIK you can't do anything about it. Is the button still invisible, after the debugging part?

Comment: Hey @dummy :) The button is visible when I'm in the editor and I press debug and the app runs, then I can't see it :3 But I don't think it's just invisible, because I can't even use the `.performclick()` from another button... Nothing happens D:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of playing around I finally found the problem!

The value was set to `=False` in my properties. I'm so blonde! Thanks guys for the help ^_^/

```
    Public Property Active_bool As Boolean
    Get
        Return btn_Begin.Visible
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        btn_Begin.Visible = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Although, Something sets the values to `=False` ever now and then. Very annoying :3 
And I can not set the value to `=True` in the properties... Only in the hidden designer code...

Answer (score 1):

This is strange. Does any MsgBoxes pop up if you add this code to your UserControl:

```
Private Sub UserControl_ControlRemoved(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.ControlEventArgs) Handles Me.ControlRemoved
    MsgBox("Control Removed!")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_EnabledChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.EnabledChanged
    MsgBox("EnabledChanged!")
End Sub
```

If so, then you can add a breakpoint to these MsgBoxes and lock at the CallStack (`CTRL+L`) from where it triggers.

Btw: If the control is removed somehow, .PerformClick() still triggers (for me). Thus I bet, that the control is somehow disabled (`Enabled = False`).

Lastly, if any container of the button (such as your UserControl) is disabled, the button will be disabled too,